# Generics to prevent Parent class to be as accepted type

Tags: java

I have a situation in which I have to create a generic method that can accept List of child objects but not the parent class objects.

Say I have

```
class ClassA {}
```

which is getting extended by

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {}
class ClassC extends ClassA {}
```

```
executeMethod(List</* either ClassB or ClassC but not ClassA */>)
```

Can we achieve it using generics?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you can't just allow `List<? extends ClassA>` but you could try:

```
<T Extends ClassA> void executeMethod(List<? extends T>);
//not sure if this will work but worth a try.
```

Or

```
public interface ClassX {}
public class ClassA {

    void executeMethod(List<? extends ClassX);
}
public ClassB extends ClassA implements ClassX {}
public ClassC extends ClassA implements ClassX {}
```

Comment: First solution does not restrict enough: you can pass a List<ClassA>. I like the second solution with an interface, that can be a _marker_. It's more flexible than creating a new intermediate class in the hierarchy as proposed by @beresfordt

Comment: hey redge .. can you plz share some code example on the same. Interface approach is gving me compilation errors: List<? implements InterfaceA> as implements is not allowed in generics. if I am using List<? extends ClassA> them I am able to assign list of ClassA, ClassB and ClassC all. I want to stop the acceptance of List<ClassA> .

Comment: The generic specifier is always `T extends S` regardless of whether S is a class or interface. There is no implements keyword in generics. So your code should read `List<? extends InterfaceA> `

Comment: Thanks redge for sharing your views ..  I tried another way also List<? super ClassA> .. but that was also accepting List<ClassA> as acceptable which I didn't want. what is the use of <? super ClassA>

Comment: This specifies that the parameter must be an instance of a superclass of ClassA. ie <? super ClassB> would be satisfied by ClassB and ClassA but not ClasaC

Answer (score 2):

Making A abstract is the easiest way to do it. If you cannot make A abstract you could create an abstract class which extends A, and then is itself extended by B and C, eg:

```
class A {

}

abstract class X extends A {

}

class B extends X {

}

class C extends X {

}

public void executeMethod(List<? extends X> list) {

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `List<? extends X>` as B and C should be allowed and A not?

Comment: Not to my understanding; there is a discussion of when to use super/extends here - [Producer Extends Consumer Super](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/658663)

Comment: The condition was: `B or C but not A`, which would be fulfilled by `extends` because `B extends X`, `C extends X` and `A not extends X`. But with `super` it's exactly the opposit thing: `B not super X`, `C not super X` but `A super X` which does not fulfill the condition.

Comment: Yeah, you're right - generics are not my strong point. Thanks for the correction, will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is cannot be done as Pshemo said there is no `or` or `not` operation for this. You could however to something like this:

```
public static void executeMethod(List<ClassB> list){ 
    sharedMethodPerhaps( ... );
}

public static void executeMethod(ArrayList<ClassC> list){
    sharedMethodPerhaps( ... );
}

private static void sharedMethodPerhaps( ... ){ 
    ...
}
```

This way you have two method with the same name and one only accepts a list with `ClassB` objects and the other only accepts a list with `ClassC` objects. And because `List` and `ArrayList` are different so enough the two methods do not collide.
And the `sharedMethodPerhaps` is private so you control what code class it and how.

I hope this help :)